# Maximum of $x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4 - 2x_5$ with some constraints

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I have to find maximum of $x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4 - 2x_5$ with constraints:

$-x_1 +x_2 + x_3 = 2$

$x_1 + 2x_2 + x_4 = 10$

$x_1 - x_2  + x_5 = 4$

of course $x_i \ge 0$.

From constrains I have:

$x_3 = 2 + x_1 - x_2$

$x_4 = 10-x_1-2x_2$

$x_5 = 4 + x_2 - x_1$

If i put it into

$x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4 - 2x_5$

i will have

$f(x_1,x_2) = x_1 - 4x_2$

What now I can do with it?

Comment: $ x_i \ge 0 \implies 2+x_1-x_2 \ge 0$,etc, you find the range of $x_1,x_2$ then you should be able to know when they get max.

Comment: To solve this Kind of problems I apply the simplex algorithm. Have you ever heard about that ?

Comment: Yes I have, but I do not remember it. And here with constraints I have "=", not "<=".

Comment: @Thomas You have equality signs. Thus you do not need slack variables. But you need artificial variables ( $a_i$) for every constraint. Maybe you should read a little bit about the simplex algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You’re really close! Let’s look at this comprehensively and solve it via the graphical method.

Given the linear model,

$$\max z = x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4-2x_5$$
Subject to:
$$-x_1+x_2+x_3=2$$
$$x_1 + 2x_2 +x_4=10$$
$$x_1-x_2+x_5=4$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\ge0$$

Since,
$$x_3=2+x_1-x_2$$
$$x_4=10-x_1-2x_2$$
$$x_5=4-x_1+x_2$$

Thus,

$$\max z = x_1-4x_2$$
Subject to:
$$2+x_1-x_2\ge0$$
$$10-x_1-2x_2\ge0$$
$$4-x_1+x_2\ge0$$
$$x_1,x_2\ge0$$

Graphically, [we can represent](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gj6b09sx52) the feasible region as the following:
[Image of Desmos Feasible Region Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhFXp.jpg)

With the following extreme points and their respective $z$ values:

$$(0,0)\quad z=0$$
$$(0,2)\quad z=-8$$
$$(2,4)\quad z=-6$$
$$(4,0)\quad z=4$$
$$(6,2)\quad z=-2$$

Since we’re looking for the maximum extreme point, $(4,0)$ will be our solution with $z=4$, but since there was substitution involved, the overall answer is $x_1=4$, $x_2=0$, $x_3=6$, $x_4= 6$, and $x_5=0$ with $z=4$.